# Nagios plugins - copy and execute?

Tags: nagios

I have a Nagios server installation up and running.
I'm starting to deploy check_mk out to all my client machines.
I am using mrpe for custom checks on my client machines.
As one of the checks, I would like to use the check_ssh plugin.
I tried to copy check_ssh from another machine to the client but it looks like it won't allow me to run it this way. Can I get away from actually installing the nagios agent and just stick to check_mk and be able to run Nagios plugins?

The exact error I am getting is:

```
ld.so.1: check_ssh: fatal: libintl.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most of the plugins in the standard nagios-plugins pack are compiled C, so if you're copying them to a different distribution or architecture they may not work.  I would consider just downloading the nagios-plugins package or grabbing the latest source package for the client machines. 
Nagios Plugins Source tarball
http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/nagiosplug/nagios-plugins-1.4.16.tar.gz

Comment: thanks Michael. I found a way around this by being able to use check_mk itself. Since it supports legacy checks and ssh is a public service, I was able to do it within main.mk itself by referring to http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_legacy_checks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check SSH without nrpe plugin, it can be done from the Nagios server, just use the check_ssh plugin with this command (launched from the server):

```
./usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ssh -H <client_ip>
```

If it's enabled it should print something like:

> SSH OK - OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1 (protocol 2.0) |
>   time=0,018154s;;;0,000000;10,000000

(That's because i'm using Debian Wheezy)

check_ssh comes with Nagios plugins tarball...

I'm currently using

> nagios-plugins-2.0.2.tar.gz

Good luck...